# Телеграм бот пишет в лс пользователю при подписке на конкретный канал

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

*Как сделать бота, который напишет в лс пользователю после того когда сам пользователь подпишеться на канал, к которому "привязан" бот? Работаю с библиотекой* `aiogram`*, соответственно язык* - `Python`

Comment: вот для начала - https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/quick_start.html 
Отлично все расписано.

Answer (score 0):

Если ты хочешь, чтобы бот сразу же после подписки писал в ЛС человеку, то нужно смотреть в возможности библиотеки на отслеживание подписки на канале.
А так можешь прикрутить кнопку для проверки подписки. URL для проверки подписки:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot[токен_бота]/getChatMember?chat_id=[айди_канала]&user_id=[айди_пользователя]
```

Answer (score 0):

Канал должен быть приватным, и чтобы ему кидали реквест на приём, только тогда бот может писать в лс:

**код:**

```
@dp.chat_join_request_handler()
async def he(link: ChatJoinRequest):
    await bot.approve_chat_join_request(link.chat.id, link.from_user.id)
    await bot.send_message(link.from_user.id, 'привет')
```